# No error, but code will not do an AJAX call inside an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, call

Currently my script has no errors and only has 2 problems in JSHint (But none of them critical (I think)). This is my script that SHOULD be working, but isn't.

```
    var hats = [31151864, 16412796, 95245701, 61847146]; 
var names = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var request = 65;

var Loop = setInterval(function () {
    for (var Id in hats) {
        var origLink = "http://www.roblox.com/"+names[Id]+"-item?id=" + hats[Id];
        $.get(origLink, function(data) {
            var Regex = /item\Dprivatesale\Dprice\D\D([\d,]+)\D\Dspan\D/;
        console.log(data.match(Regex)[1]);
            var PriceSelling = data.match(Regex)[1];
            if (PriceSelling <= request) {
                var hatBuying = "http://m.roblox.com/items/" + hats[Id] + "/privatesales";
console.log(hatBuying);
    $.get(hatBuying, function(data){console.log("Success!");
                    var Regex2 = /Catalog\DVerifyTransfer\DuserAssetOptionId\D([\d,]+)\Damp\DexpectedPrice\D/+PriceSelling+/\D\D/;
                    var buyId = data.match(Regex2)[1];
                                        console.log(buyId);
                    var buyLink = "http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/VerifyTransfer?userAssetOptionId=" + buyId + "&expectedPrice=" + PriceSelling;
                    var Explorer = document.createElement('iframe');

                    function Buy() {
                        Explorer.contentDocument.forms[0].submit();
                    }

                    Explorer.onload = Buy;
                    Explorer.width = "300";
                    Explorer.height = "400";
                    Explorer.src = buyLink;
                    document.body.innerHTML = "";
                    document.body.appendChild(Explorer);
                    clearInterval(Loop);
                });
            }
        });
    }
console.log("!");
}, 500);
```

Currently, hat 4 (d) is selling for 65 'robux' currency, and so the output I get is this:

65
http://m.roblox.com/items/61847146/privatesales

What is happening? It does not even start the second AJAX call even though it should. Please help? Thanks!

Comment: I see Same Origin Policy problems.

Comment: I'm only a few lines in and found a bug: `"http://www.roblox.com/"+names[Id]+"-item?id="`  Id is not an array index.  All values for "Id" are in the millions but your array has 4 elements.  This will result in, at best, the "undefined" value and at worst, a runtime exception.

Comment: @Brandon no, "Id" will be the indexes of the "hats" array. In JavaScript, a `for ... in` loop iterates through the *keys* of an object, not the values.

Comment: The main problem is going to be that there's one "Id" variable shared among all the callback functions. Its value will be 5 by the time they run.

Comment: I set at the beginning Id to "var Id in hats" so that would mean it is 1-4, right?

Comment: @user2977150 0-3, since arrays are 0-indexed.

Comment: Also don't use `for ... in` to iterate through arrays in JavaScript. Use a simple `for` loop with an explicit index, or else use `.forEach()`.

Comment: Pointy can you give me an example of this code using .forEach() or a for loop? I thought I have to use for... in

Comment: How would I set a variable to be the number of hats? I'm new to JavaScript, I'm only decent in a variation of Lua script, which basically nothing uses :p so I'm pretty useless in this area.

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: @Pointy, thanks for the correction.  You're right.  That is one reason why I avoid using a `for x in y` pattern in JavaScript as it makes it confusing what you are iterating over.

Comment: You keep saying I should use a for loop, not a for x in y loop, why? And can I plaese can an example??